# SQL Query to Count number of values in a column Per Month Conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
id   date          sales  req      arivve
1    01/01/2015    100    accept   deny
2    01/01/2015    100    deny     deny
3    02/01/2015    100    accept   accept
4    03/01/2015    100    accept   deny
```

What I need is to count the number of 'accept' value in both req and arrive column per month range. This is the expected output

```
Month  StartMonth  EndMonth     TotalSales reqCount  arriveAcount
1      01/01/2015  01/31/2015   200        1         0
2      02/01/2015  02/28/2015   100        1         1
3      03/01/2015  03/31/2015   100        1         0
4      04/01/2015  04/30/2015   0          0         0
```

This is what I have already (input of start and end year is provided by user so the month tange is dynamic)

```
--step 1
select id, date, capacity, sales, req, arrive
into #First
from Sales
where date between @StartDate and @EndDate;


--step 2 b
WITH cte
    AS
    (SELECT
          FORMAT(MONTH([schedule_date]), '0#')
        + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR([schedule_date])) monthyear 
        ,([capacity]), request_status, arrival_status
    FROM #First)


    SELECT
    (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, SUBSTRING(monthyear, 1, 2) - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, SUBSTRING(monthyear, 4, 4) - 1900, 0)))    StartDate
    ,(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(SUBSTRING(monthyear, 1, 2) AS INT), DATEADD(YEAR, SUBSTRING(monthyear, 4, 4) - 1900, 0)))) EndDate
    ,SUM(capacity) totalsales   

    FROM cte
    GROUP BY monthyear
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select DATEPART(month, date)
, date as StartMonth
, dateadd(day, -1 , DATEADD(month, 1, date))
, sum(sales)
, sum(case when req = 'accept' then 1 else 0 end) reqCount
, sum(case when arivve = 'accept' then 1 else 0 end) arriveCount
from mytable
group by date
```

Comment: Good answer. This assumes that the date is always the first day in the month (as is shown in the sample data). An `ORDER BY` clause would be good.